# Golang template serving css on different directory levels

Tags: html, css, go

I'm using golang's "html/template" package to serve content on multiple pages using the same _base.html as a framework. I merge multiple html files (_base.html and the content file) to serve as one.

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
http.HandleFunc("/blog/", blogHandler)
http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("http/css"))))
http.ListenAndServe(":1337", nil)
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
index := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    "http/html/_base.html",
    "http/html/index.html",
))
index.Execute(w, nil)
}

func blogHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
blog := template.Must(template.ParseFiles(
    "http/html/_base.html",
    "http/html/blog.html",
))
blog.Execute(w, nil)
}
```

Doing so on the root of my webserver my css renders just fine, because the html link tag to my .css in _base.html points to the right directory using:

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

however when I navigate from / to /blog/ my css went a level down (or I went a level up, however you'd like to see it) and so the css href suddenly points to /blog/css/style.css and thus it won't render.

This can be easily fixed stating the level of the css in every content-file I merge with _base.html, however I feel there has to be another, cleaner, different way. Is there or is my gut misjudging in this case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Didn't test it, so I'm not really sure, but what about changing

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

?